# Producing a final score from time factor and a percentage

Tags: functions

If I have two factors, a processing time in seconds and a success percentage, how can I produce a final value that shows the success score?

for example, if I have object A has 154000 seconds with 0.9 and B object has 131000 seconds with 0.8.

note: lower processing time object is better.

Are there a specific formula or equation for such issue?

Comment: You need to come up with some weights; What is more important, the processing time or the success percentage in this case?

Comment: @EndriMani the success percentage

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, and you will likely need to change the formula to capture best what's important to you.

Just stabbing in the dark because there's no context:

- Factor in the success fraction $s$ as its square. So a success fraction of $0.8$ would give $0.64$, and $0.9$ would give $0.81$.
- Factor in processing time as $T = 200$ (thousands of seconds) minus the actual processing time $t$. So $154$ would give a factor of $46$, and $131$ would give a factor of $69$.

From here just calculate $s^2(T-t)$: $0.81 \times 46 = 37.26$, and $0.64 \times 69 = 44.16$.

Does this work for what you want? I don't have the slightest clue. But that's the idea: Factor in things, adjust the weight, and iterate until you get something you can use.

Comment: Its near, but what if we choose that the success fraction is more important ?

Comment: Also, what we can call the "200" if we need to write the equation in an algorithmic way?

Comment: I just came up with something that gets larger if (a) your success fraction is higher, given constant processing time, and (b) your processing time goes down, given constant success fraction. If you want *high* success fraction to be more important, then you could increase the power. As for $200$ I picked it out of the air. You'll need to look at your trade space to see what pairings you want to have a higher score.